# Putting my Widgets into a Column in Flutter breaks everything

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

I am, as an excercise for myself, trying to recreate the IMDb app. I am doing this to learn to as closely as possible follow something to learn to get things to look as they should. It is becoming rather complicated with Columns in Rows in Columns, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, but it works like this (do tell me though if my code is fundamentally wrong).

[The Page, when they are not in a column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAo5O.jpg)

I have tried many things and even having the empty column there in the code and the text and button below, it works perfectly (as in, the button is next to the text, not beneath, as it should be, but it does not crash)

The part encased by the many ///// is the 'problem zone', i don't know what is needed for context

```dart
Card(
    color: (HSVColor.fromAHSV(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.22)).toColor(),
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (rect) {
              return LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
              ).createShader(
                  Rect.fromLTRB(0, 200, rect.width, rect.height));
            },
            blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
            child: Image.asset("assets/movies/" +
                _movie.getImagePath() +
                '/banner1.bmp'),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: _movie.getName() + '\n\n',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                    children: <TextSpan>[],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Text(
              "\n " +
                  _movie.getReleaseYear() +
                  "    " +
                  _movie.getDuration().toString() +
                  "min     Directed by: " +
                  _movie.getDirector(),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70))),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
      ),
      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
              "assets/movies/" +
                  _movie.getImagePath() +
                  '/poster.bmp',
              height: 240,
              width: 160),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          ),
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    _movie.getDescription(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ))),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.blue,
          )
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ],
      )
    ])),
```

as you might see, all i did here is drag and drop the Expanded and Button into the Column.

```dart
Card(
    color: (HSVColor.fromAHSV(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.22)).toColor(),
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ShaderMask(
            shaderCallback: (rect) {
              return LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
              ).createShader(
                  Rect.fromLTRB(0, 200, rect.width, rect.height));
            },
            blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
            child: Image.asset("assets/movies/" +
                _movie.getImagePath() +
                '/banner1.bmp'),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                RichText(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: _movie.getName() + '\n\n',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                    children: <TextSpan>[],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Text(
              "\n " +
                  _movie.getReleaseYear() +
                  "    " +
                  _movie.getDuration().toString() +
                  "min     Directed by: " +
                  _movie.getDirector(),
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70))),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
      ),

      Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
              "assets/movies/" +
                  _movie.getImagePath() +
                  '/poster.bmp',
              height: 240,
              width: 160),

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          ),
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          Column(children: <Widget>[

            Expanded(
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      _movie.getDescription(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ))),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blue,
            )
          ],),
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ],
      )
    ])),
```

I then get 22 error messages

```
════════ (2) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#46c16 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:28:22
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (3) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#1ecab relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (4) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#bf879 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (5) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#23d9c relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (6) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderInkFeatures#d5fb8 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (7) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#c42f6 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (8) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#af491 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (9) Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#82ff0 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (10) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#d9b34 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:12:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (11) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#f2c36 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:12:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (12) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(1e-10)
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:12:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (13) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#1ecab relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (14) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#bf879 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (15) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#23d9c relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (16) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderInkFeatures#d5fb8 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (17) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#c42f6 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (18) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#af491 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (19) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#82ff0 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Card file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:26:11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (20) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#d9b34 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:12:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (21) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#f2c36 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1681 pos 12: 'hasSize'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:12:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (22) Exception caught by rendering library ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(1e-10)
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/xxx/dev/flutter_testapp2/lib/movie_detailed_widget.dart:12:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I know for someone knowing flutter, they might say 'oh is it not obvious, looking at the error messages cleatly shows that...', but i am very new to flutter, and none of this makes any sense to me, especially not why this might break

Since i literally just put the 2 widgets into the column and there are no error messages, i just expect it to work. i tried playing around a lot, changing things, but it always works unless it is in the column.

Edit 1: I managed to get it to not crash, the only thing keeping me from happiness is actually the 'Expanded' that makes things not work. without it: fine

Edit 2: More trial and error. So, i can not use flexible. With or without align, it does not work. It works without flexible, but then the screen overflows. I have no idea what to do, and honestly, i am more confused than before. Flexible and Expanded both don't work. What am i doing wrong

Comment: try to add flex into expanded like this :  Expanded(flex : 5  // for 50% or 2 // ... , child : ... )

Comment: @GirlWhoCode i have no idea what this means, but it does not seem to have changed anything

Comment: delete the Align(child: ) ,  if u have the same error, then its not about this part of your code.

Comment: I accidentaly deleted Expanded instead of Align, but now it does work just going off and overflowing the border

Comment: I also added the button back in, which gives me no exception, but it does not appear

Comment: Correction, the butten is added, but centered under the middle of the text and was not visible under longer text

Comment: @GirlWhoCode I edited the question to show what (does not) work(s), so, if you have any ideas, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is wrap your culprit `column` with `flexible` widget.

Code:

```
Card(
          color: (HSVColor.fromAHSV(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.22)).toColor(),
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                ShaderMask(
                  shaderCallback: (rect) {
                    return LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
                    ).createShader(
                        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 200, rect.width, rect.height));
                  },
                  blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
                  child: Image.network('https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech'),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      RichText(
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text: 'Dummy Movie' + '\n\n',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                          children: <TextSpan>[],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Text(
                    "\n " +
                        '2019' +
                        "    " +
                        '2h 30 Min' +
                        "min     Directed by: " +
                        'Anmol Majhail',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70))),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.network(
                  'https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech',
                  height: 240,
                  width: 160,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                ),
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Flexible(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            'This is Dummy Description. Just to fill up the space.',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          )),
                      RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
              ],
            )
          ]))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. Could you tell me though why it is, that I cannot put the Flexible in the Column? Is this wrong?

Comment: We want parent row to allow Column to take up space as per its children. so we wrap it with flexible.